# Using dates in MySQL or PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a requirement based on dates, where I need to show the count for the staff on the particular date range, Sundays & government holidays should not be counted.

```
------------------------------------------
|Staff name| less | Full | more | Absent |
------------------------------------------
| name 1   | 1    | 3    | 1    |  1     |
------------------------------------------
| name 2   | 2    | 2    | 2    | 0      |
------------------------------------------
```

This is my requirement:

1. Sundays should not be counted
2. Saturdays will have 4 hours of effort
3. Week days will have 8 hours of effort

But staff can enter lower or higher than the fixed one.
Here in the table if the staff has worked for 7 hours will be counted +1 in less column, if he works more than 8 hours will be counted +1 in more, if he works exactly 8 hours will be counted +1 in full column, if he absent on the particular date +1 will be counted in absent column.

For Saturday: same as the above but 8 hours will be considered as 4 hours.'
Sunday should not be counted in anyways.

For this requirement do I need to have a new MySQL table consists of all the 365 days of the year with Sundays & govt holidays with in active status??
or we can do it without having table? if so how to do it, pls explain.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

```
$day_of_week = date("D");
```

That will show you the current day of the week so that will help you know if it is "Sat" or "Sun".

as for the govt holidays, you will need to store those in a table. Probably the easiest way is to have day, month, year. Then you can find out the current day like this:

```
$mon = date("m");
$day = date("d");
$year = date("Y");
```

Just use those variables to construct a query and make sure the current date isnt a holiday:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM holidays WHERE day='".$day."' AND month='".$month."' AND year='".$year."'";
....execute query
```

Comment: Well, thanks @pogeybait for the reply, I will check this & post the results shortly.